# How to use templates for multiple data types (string, int, float)?

Tags: c++, templates

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to use templates for a C++ function that can accept three data types: int, float, and string. I need to be able to perform calculations on the input as if it were an integer as well. Can someone provide an example of this using these data types?

I was hoping for code that would run, for example:

```
isPrimeNumber("25");
isPrimeNumber(25);
isPrimeNumber(25.5);
```

What I mean by "perform calculations" is, for example:

```
t = t % 2;
t = t / 2;
```

I have tried everything I can find on google, and nothing is working.. help is much appreciated.

Edit:

Here is my Prime class:

```
class Prime {
    public:
    template<class T1>
    char isPrimeNumber(T1 i)
    {
       // ... Checks for prime number here, returns 'P' or 'N'
    }
    
    template<>
    char isPrimeNumber(std::string s) { }

    template<>
    char isPrimeNumber(float f) { }

}
```

This code gives the error:
"error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Prime' template<>
^"

If I move the specializations outside the class, this error goes away, but a new one pops up: "error: 'isPrimeNumber' is not a template function'"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222958/discussion-on-question-by-oxenfreehorchata-how-to-use-templates-for-multiple-dat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the specialised functions inside the class doesn't work because you get this error

> error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Prime’

So this won't work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Prime
{
public:
    template<class T1>
    char calculate(T1 i)
    {
        std::cout << "calculate(T1 " << i << ")\n";
        i = i % 2;
    }
    
    template<>
    char calculate(std::string s)
    {
        std::cout << "calculate<std::string>(std::string " << s << ")\n";
    }
    
    template<>
    char calculate(float f)
    {
        std::cout << "calculate<float>(float " << f << ")\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Prime p;
    p.calculate(std::string("25"));
    p.calculate(25);
    p.calculate(25.5f);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/HyKXjjfPw

But defining the member functions outside the class does work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Prime
{
public:
    template<class T1>
    char calculate(T1 i);
};

template<class T1>
char Prime::calculate(T1 i)
{
    std::cout << "calculate(T1 " << i << ")\n";
    i = i % 2;
}

template<>
char Prime::calculate(std::string s)
{
    std::cout << "calculate<std::string>(std::string " << s << ")\n";
}

template<>
char Prime::calculate(float f)
{
    std::cout << "calculate<float>(float " << f << ")\n";
}

int main()
{
    Prime p;
    p.calculate(std::string("25"));
    p.calculate(25);
    p.calculate(25.5f);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkwEjjMDD

Comment: Okay. I did a little reading and I understand why the specializations have to be outside the class.. I moved them and my code is working! Thanks for the help!